# Centering container inside full-width container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to center a container of max width 1100px relative to a container of 100% width, but I'm having trouble doing it.

```
<div class="container-full">
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <h1>Name</h1>
            <ul>
                 <li>Home</li>
                 <li>About</li>
                 <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-full {
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
}

.container {
    width:1100px;
    background-color:white;
}

nav {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    display:flex;
}
```

I think it has something to do with the nav being a flex-box, but I'm not sure how I can solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to horizontally center something with a defined width is to use `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

```css
.container-full {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  width: 1100px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-full">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <h1>Name</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add margins to your container:

```
   margin: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to add `margin: 0 auto;` to your `.container`.

See working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fpxxyc94/)

[image]

```css
.container-full {
    width:100%;
    background: blue;
}

.container {
    width:1100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-full">
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <h1>Name</h1>
            <ul>
                 <li>Home</li>
                 <li>About</li>
                 <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I am not sure what you want to do. If you are trying to center the contents of container relative to container-full, then the below might work.

If you will like to center anything, then you may want to use the following mixin.

exaple codepen link: http://codepen.io/hellouniverse/pen/PWyVbd

```
@mixin  align-items () {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@mixin flexbox() {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

@mixin justify-content ($val) {
  -webkit-justify-content: $val;
  -moz-justify-content: $val;
  -ms-justify-content: $val;
  justify-content: $val;
}


%aligner,
.aligner {
  @include align-items();
  @include flexbox();
  @include justify-content(center);

  &-item {
    max-width: 50%;
    &--top {
      -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
      -moz-align-content: flex-start;
      -ms-align-content: flex-start;
      -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
      align-content: flex-start;
    }

    &--bottom {
      -webkit-align-content: flex-end;
      -moz-align-content: flex-end;
      -ms-align-content: flex-end;
      -ms-flex-line-pack: end;
      align-content: flex-end;
    }
  }
}
```

And your solution will become after adding the above scss mixin

```
.container-full {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  width: 1100px;
  background-color: white;
}

<div class="container-full aligner">
    <div class="container aligner">
        <nav>
            <h1>Name</h1>
            <ul>
                 <li>Home</li>
                 <li>About</li>
                 <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```